# react-native TextInput element has no method of blur and focus

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-ref, react-native-textinput

I'm trying to control focus moving between few textInput elements, but they have no method of blur and focus. I've been struggled by this issue during the day. I have tried every solution I have searched and found on the web, but none of them are the solution of this. I'm not sure, if there is problem on my code or using wrong way of refs. I'm now using `"react": "17.0.2"` and `"react-native": "^0.66.4"` for my project, have checked the documentation of react-native and was not able to find any changes currently. Please help me out!!

these are my code.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const template = (props) => {
    const onEndEditing = (e) => {
        console.log(inputRef.current);
        // setInputFocus;
    }
        
    const useFocus = () => {
        const htmlElRef = useRef(null);
        const setFocus = () => {htmlElRef.current &&  htmlElRef.current.focus()};
        
        return [ htmlElRef, setFocus ];
    };
    
    const [inputRef, setInputFocus] = useFocus();

    return ( 
        <View style={ styles.container }>
            <Text style={styles.title}>id</Text>
            <TextInput 
                clearTextOnFocus={true}
                ref={inputRef}
                onEndEditing={(e) => onEndEditing(e)}
            >
            </TextInput>
        </View>
    )
};


export default template;
```

below is all the properties in `inputRef.current`

```
{
    "_children": [],
    "_internalFiberInstanceHandleDEV": {
        "_debugHookTypes": null,
        "_debugNeedsRemount": false,
        "_debugOwner": {
            "_debugHookTypes": [Array
            ],
            "_debugNeedsRemount": false,
            "_debugOwner": [FiberNode
            ],
            "_debugSource": [Object
            ],
            "actualDuration": 0.13012400083243847,
            "actualStartTime": 12217585.480157,
            "alternate": [FiberNode
            ],
            "child": [FiberNode
            ],
            "childLanes": 0,
            "deletions": null,
            "dependencies": null,
            "elementType": [Function InternalTextInput
            ],
            "flags": 1048581,
            "index": 0,
            "key": null,
            "lanes": 0,
            "memoizedProps": [Object
            ],
            "memoizedState": [Object
            ],
            "mode": 2,
            "pendingProps": [Object
            ],
            "ref": null,
            "return": [FiberNode
            ],
            "selfBaseDuration": 0.10079099982976913,
            "sibling": null,
            "stateNode": null,
            "subtreeFlags": 260,
            "tag": 0,
            "treeBaseDuration": 0.10983200185000896,
            "type": [Function InternalTextInput
            ],
            "updateQueue": [Object
            ]
        },
        "_debugSource": {
            "columnNumber": 7,
            "fileName": "/Users/ethanshin/Dev/moms_mobile/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/TextInput/TextInput.js",
            "lineNumber": 1186
        },
        "actualDuration": 0.02183300070464611,
        "actualStartTime": 12217585.587698,
        "alternate": {
            "_debugHookTypes": null,
            "_debugNeedsRemount": false,
            "_debugOwner": [FiberNode
            ],
            "_debugSource": [Object
            ],
            "actualDuration": 0.008542003110051155,
            "actualStartTime": 12217584.57749,
            "alternate": [Circular
            ],
            "child": null,
            "childLanes": 0,
            "deletions": null,
            "dependencies": null,
            "elementType": "AndroidTextInput",
            "flags": 260,
            "index": 0,
            "key": null,
            "lanes": 0,
            "memoizedProps": [Object
            ],
            "memoizedState": null,
            "mode": 2,
            "pendingProps": [Object
            ],
            "ref": [Function forwardRef
            ],
            "return": [FiberNode
            ],
            "selfBaseDuration": 0.0050420016050338745,
            "sibling": null,
            "stateNode": [Circular
            ],
            "subtreeFlags": 0,
            "tag": 5,
            "treeBaseDuration": 0.0050420016050338745,
            "type": "AndroidTextInput",
            "updateQueue": null
        },
        "child": null,
        "childLanes": 0,
        "deletions": null,
        "dependencies": null,
        "elementType": "AndroidTextInput",
        "flags": 260,
        "index": 0,
        "key": null,
        "lanes": 0,
        "memoizedProps": {
            "accessible": true,
            "allowFontScaling": true,
            "autoCapitalize": "sentences",
            "blurOnSubmit": true,
            "caretHidden": undefined,
            "children": undefined,
            "clearTextOnFocus": true,
            "collapsable": false,
            "disableFullscreenUI": undefined,
            "focusable": true,
            "forwardedRef": [Function anonymous
            ],
            "mostRecentEventCount": 3,
            "onBlur": [Function _onBlur
            ],
            "onChange": [Function _onChange
            ],
            "onClick": [Function onClick
            ],
            "onEndEditing": [Function onEndEditing
            ],
            "onFocus": [Function _onFocus
            ],
            "onGestureHandlerEvent": [Function anonymous
            ],
            "onGestureHandlerStateChange": [Function anonymous
            ],
            "onResponderGrant": [Function onResponderGrant
            ],
            "onResponderMove": [Function onResponderMove
            ],
            "onResponderRelease": [Function onResponderRelease
            ],
            "onResponderTerminate": [Function onResponderTerminate
            ],
            "onResponderTerminationRequest": [Function onResponderTerminationRequest
            ],
            "onScroll": [Function _onScroll
            ],
            "onSelectionChange": [Function _onSelectionChange
            ],
            "onStartShouldSetResponder": [Function onStartShouldSetResponder
            ],
            "placeholder": "",
            "rejectResponderTermination": true,
            "selection": null,
            "style": [Array
            ],
            "text": "",
            "textBreakStrategy": undefined,
            "underlineColorAndroid": "transparent"
        },
        "memoizedState": null,
        "mode": 2,
        "pendingProps": {
            "accessible": true,
            "allowFontScaling": true,
            "autoCapitalize": "sentences",
            "blurOnSubmit": true,
            "caretHidden": undefined,
            "children": undefined,
            "clearTextOnFocus": true,
            "collapsable": false,
            "disableFullscreenUI": undefined,
            "focusable": true,
            "forwardedRef": [Function anonymous
            ],
            "mostRecentEventCount": 3,
            "onBlur": [Function _onBlur
            ],
            "onChange": [Function _onChange
            ],
            "onClick": [Function onClick
            ],
            "onEndEditing": [Function onEndEditing
            ],
            "onFocus": [Function _onFocus
            ],
            "onGestureHandlerEvent": [Function anonymous
            ],
            "onGestureHandlerStateChange": [Function anonymous
            ],
            "onResponderGrant": [Function onResponderGrant
            ],
            "onResponderMove": [Function onResponderMove
            ],
            "onResponderRelease": [Function onResponderRelease
            ],
            "onResponderTerminate": [Function onResponderTerminate
            ],
            "onResponderTerminationRequest": [Function onResponderTerminationRequest
            ],
            "onScroll": [Function _onScroll
            ],
            "onSelectionChange": [Function _onSelectionChange
            ],
            "onStartShouldSetResponder": [Function onStartShouldSetResponder
            ],
            "placeholder": "",
            "rejectResponderTermination": true,
            "selection": null,
            "style": [Array
            ],
            "text": "",
            "textBreakStrategy": undefined,
            "underlineColorAndroid": "transparent"
        },
        "ref": [Function forwardRef
        ],
        "return": {
            "_debugHookTypes": null,
            "_debugNeedsRemount": false,
            "_debugOwner": [FiberNode
            ],
            "_debugSource": [Object
            ],
            "actualDuration": 0.028791001066565514,
            "actualStartTime": 12217585.581782,
            "alternate": [FiberNode
            ],
            "child": [Circular
            ],
            "childLanes": 0,
            "deletions": null,
            "dependencies": null,
            "elementType": [Object
            ],
            "flags": 0,
            "index": 0,
            "key": null,
            "lanes": 0,
            "memoizedProps": [Object
            ],
            "memoizedState": null,
            "mode": 2,
            "pendingProps": [Object
            ],
            "ref": null,
            "return": [FiberNode
            ],
            "selfBaseDuration": 0.005458001047372818,
            "sibling": null,
            "stateNode": null,
            "subtreeFlags": 260,
            "tag": 10,
            "treeBaseDuration": 0.00904100202023983,
            "type": [Object
            ],
            "updateQueue": null
        },
        "selfBaseDuration": 0.003583000972867012,
        "sibling": null,
        "stateNode": [Circular
        ],
        "subtreeFlags": 0,
        "tag": 5,
        "treeBaseDuration": 0.003583000972867012,
        "type": "AndroidTextInput",
        "updateQueue": null
    },
    "_nativeTag": 53,
    "clear": [Function clear
    ],
    "getNativeRef": [Function getNativeRef
    ],
    "handlerTag": 1,
    "isFocused": [Function isFocused
    ],
    "viewConfig": {
        "Commands": {
            "blurTextInput": 2,
            "focusTextInput": 1
        },
        "Constants": {
            "AutoCapitalizationType": [Object
            ]
        },
        "NativeProps": {
            "accessibilityActions": "Array",
            "accessibilityHint": "String",
            "accessibilityLabel": "String",
            "accessibilityLiveRegion": "String",
            "accessibilityRole": "String",
            "accessibilityState": "Map",
            "accessibilityValue": "Map",
            "adjustsFontSizeToFit": "boolean",
            "alignContent": "String",
            "alignItems": "String",
            "alignSelf": "String",
            "allowFontScaling": "boolean",
            "aspectRatio": "number",
            "autoCapitalize": "mixed",
            "autoComplete": "String",
            "autoCorrect": "boolean",
            "autoFocus": "boolean",
            "backgroundColor": "Color",
            "blurOnSubmit": "boolean",
            "borderBottomColor": "Color",
            "borderBottomLeftRadius": "number",
            "borderBottomRightRadius": "number",
            "borderBottomWidth": "number",
            "borderColor": "Color",
            "borderEndWidth": "number",
            "borderLeftColor": "Color",
            "borderLeftWidth": "number",
            "borderRadius": "number",
            "borderRightColor": "Color",
            "borderRightWidth": "number",
            "borderStartWidth": "number",
            "borderStyle": "String",
            "borderTopColor": "Color",
            "borderTopLeftRadius": "number",
            "borderTopRightRadius": "number",
            "borderTopWidth": "number",
            "borderWidth": "number",
            "bottom": "mixed",
            "caretHidden": "boolean",
            "collapsable": "boolean",
            "color": "Color",
            "contextMenuHidden": "boolean",
            "cursorColor": "Color",
            "disableFullscreenUI": "boolean",
            "display": "String",
            "editable": "boolean",
            "elevation": "number",
            "end": "mixed",
            "flex": "number",
            "flexBasis": "mixed",
            "flexDirection": "String",
            "flexGrow": "number",
            "flexShrink": "number",
            "flexWrap": "String",
            "fontFamily": "String",
            "fontSize": "number",
            "fontStyle": "String",
            "fontVariant": "Array",
            "fontWeight": "String",
            "height": "mixed",
            "importantForAccessibility": "String",
            "importantForAutofill": "String",
            "includeFontPadding": "boolean",
            "inlineImageLeft": "String",
            "inlineImagePadding": "number",
            "justifyContent": "String",
            "keyboardType": "String",
            "left": "mixed",
            "letterSpacing": "number",
            "lineHeight": "number",
            "margin": "mixed",
            "marginBottom": "mixed",
            "marginEnd": "mixed",
            "marginHorizontal": "mixed",
            "marginLeft": "mixed",
            "marginRight": "mixed",
            "marginStart": "mixed",
            "marginTop": "mixed",
            "marginVertical": "mixed",
            "maxFontSizeMultiplier": "number",
            "maxHeight": "mixed",
            "maxLength": "number",
            "maxWidth": "mixed",
            "minHeight": "mixed",
            "minWidth": "mixed",
            "minimumFontScale": "number",
            "mostRecentEventCount": "number",
            "multiline": "boolean",
            "nativeID": "String",
            "numberOfLines": "number",
            "onContentSizeChange": "boolean",
            "onKeyPress": "boolean",
            "onLayout": "boolean",
            "onScroll": "boolean",
            "onSelectionChange": "boolean",
            "opacity": "number",
            "overflow": "String",
            "padding": "mixed",
            "paddingBottom": "mixed",
            "paddingEnd": "mixed",
            "paddingHorizontal": "mixed",
            "paddingLeft": "mixed",
            "paddingRight": "mixed",
            "paddingStart": "mixed",
            "paddingTop": "mixed",
            "paddingVertical": "mixed",
            "placeholder": "String",
            "placeholderTextColor": "Color",
            "position": "String",
            "renderToHardwareTextureAndroid": "boolean",
            "returnKeyLabel": "String",
            "returnKeyType": "String",
            "right": "mixed",
            "rotation": "number",
            "scaleX": "number",
            "scaleY": "number",
            "secureTextEntry": "boolean",
            "selectTextOnFocus": "boolean",
            "selection": "Map",
            "selectionColor": "Color",
            "shadowColor": "Color",
            "showSoftInputOnFocus": "boolean",
            "start": "mixed",
            "testID": "String",
            "text": "String",
            "textAlign": "String",
            "textAlignVertical": "String",
            "textBreakStrategy": "String",
            "textDecorationLine": "String",
            "textShadowColor": "Color",
            "textShadowOffset": "Map",
            "textShadowRadius": "number",
            "textTransform": "String",
            "top": "mixed",
            "transform": "Array",
            "translateX": "number",
            "translateY": "number",
            "underlineColorAndroid": "Color",
            "width": "mixed",
            "zIndex": "number"
        },
        "bubblingEventTypes": {
            "topBlur": [Object
            ],
            "topEndEditing": [Object
            ],
            "topFocus": [Object
            ],
            "topKeyPress": [Object
            ],
            "topSubmitEditing": [Object
            ],
            "topTextInput": [Object
            ]
        },
        "directEventTypes": {
            "topScroll": [Object
            ]
        },
        "uiViewClassName": "AndroidTextInput",
        "validAttributes": {
            "accessibilityActions": true,
            "accessibilityHint": true,
            "accessibilityLabel": true,
            "accessibilityLiveRegion": true,
            "accessibilityRole": true,
            "accessibilityState": true,
            "accessibilityValue": true,
            "adjustsFontSizeToFit": true,
            "alignContent": true,
            "alignItems": true,
            "alignSelf": true,
            "allowFontScaling": true,
            "aspectRatio": true,
            "autoCapitalize": true,
            "autoComplete": true,
            "autoCorrect": true,
            "autoFocus": true,
            "backgroundColor": [Object
            ],
            "blurOnSubmit": true,
            "borderBottomColor": [Object
            ],
            "borderBottomLeftRadius": true,
            "borderBottomRightRadius": true,
            "borderBottomWidth": true,
            "borderColor": [Object
            ],
            "borderEndWidth": true,
            "borderLeftColor": [Object
            ],
            "borderLeftWidth": true,
            "borderRadius": true,
            "borderRightColor": [Object
            ],
            "borderRightWidth": true,
            "borderStartWidth": true,
            "borderStyle": true,
            "borderTopColor": [Object
            ],
            "borderTopLeftRadius": true,
            "borderTopRightRadius": true,
            "borderTopWidth": true,
            "borderWidth": true,
            "bottom": true,
            "caretHidden": true,
            "collapsable": true,
            "color": [Object
            ],
            "contextMenuHidden": true,
            "cursorColor": [Object
            ],
            "disableFullscreenUI": true,
            "display": true,
            "editable": true,
            "elevation": true,
            "end": true,
            "flex": true,
            "flexBasis": true,
            "flexDirection": true,
            "flexGrow": true,
            "flexShrink": true,
            "flexWrap": true,
            "fontFamily": true,
            "fontSize": true,
            "fontStyle": true,
            "fontVariant": true,
            "fontWeight": true,
            "height": true,
            "importantForAccessibility": true,
            "importantForAutofill": true,
            "includeFontPadding": true,
            "inlineImageLeft": true,
            "inlineImagePadding": true,
            "justifyContent": true,
            "keyboardType": true,
            "left": true,
            "letterSpacing": true,
            "lineHeight": true,
            "margin": true,
            "marginBottom": true,
            "marginEnd": true,
            "marginHorizontal": true,
            "marginLeft": true,
            "marginRight": true,
            "marginStart": true,
            "marginTop": true,
            "marginVertical": true,
            "maxFontSizeMultiplier": true,
            "maxHeight": true,
            "maxLength": true,
            "maxWidth": true,
            "minHeight": true,
            "minWidth": true,
            "minimumFontScale": true,
            "mostRecentEventCount": true,
            "multiline": true,
            "nativeID": true,
            "numberOfLines": true,
            "onContentSizeChange": true,
            "onKeyPress": true,
            "onLayout": true,
            "onScroll": true,
            "onSelectionChange": true,
            "opacity": true,
            "overflow": true,
            "padding": true,
            "paddingBottom": true,
            "paddingEnd": true,
            "paddingHorizontal": true,
            "paddingLeft": true,
            "paddingRight": true,
            "paddingStart": true,
            "paddingTop": true,
            "paddingVertical": true,
            "placeholder": true,
            "placeholderTextColor": [Object
            ],
            "position": true,
            "renderToHardwareTextureAndroid": true,
            "returnKeyLabel": true,
            "returnKeyType": true,
            "right": true,
            "rotation": true,
            "scaleX": true,
            "scaleY": true,
            "secureTextEntry": true,
            "selectTextOnFocus": true,
            "selection": true,
            "selectionColor": [Object
            ],
            "shadowColor": [Object
            ],
            "showSoftInputOnFocus": true,
            "start": true,
            "style": [Object
            ],
            "testID": true,
            "text": true,
            "textAlign": true,
            "textAlignVertical": true,
            "textBreakStrategy": true,
            "textDecorationLine": true,
            "textShadowColor": [Object
            ],
            "textShadowOffset": true,
            "textShadowRadius": true,
            "textTransform": true,
            "top": true,
            "transform": true,
            "translateX": true,
            "translateY": true,
            "underlineColorAndroid": [Object
            ],
            "width": true,
            "zIndex": true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
Import { View, Text,TextInput } from 'react-native';

const template = (props) => { 

const inputRef = useRef(); //set input ref

const onEndEditing = (e) => {
    console.log(inputRef.focus()); //use ref

}
    
return ( 
    <View style={ styles.container }>
        <Text style={styles.title}>id</Text>
        <TextInput 
            clearTextOnFocus={true}
            ref={inputRef}
            onEndEditing={(e) => onEndEditing(e)}
        >
        </TextInput>
    </View>
)
};
```

try this code

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet,SafeAreaView,StatusBar,TextInput,View} from 'react-native';

const App = props => {
const inputRef = useRef();

const onEndEditing = e => {
   console.log(inputRef);
   inputRef?.current?.focus();
};
return (
  <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
   <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <TextInput
      style={styles.input}
      clearTextOnFocus={true}
      ref={inputRef}
      onEndEditing={e => onEndEditing(e)}
    />
    <TextInput style={styles.input} />
   </View>
 </SafeAreaView>
);
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
     flex: 1,
     paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
     marginHorizontal: 16,
    },
 input: {
     height: 40,
     margin: 12,
     borderWidth: 1,
     padding: 10,
 },
});
export default App;
```

you should use inputRef?.current to access focus and blur methods